# Device or Resource busy when trying to use mv

Tags: 20.04, mv

I am attempting to recover from finger problems where some data was moved to the wrong place when using Ubuntu 20.04. Below are my attempted command and the result.

```
jgossage@JFGPER:/media/jgossage$ mv LinuxData/Downloads/Downloads/Downloads/. LinuxData/Downloads -v
mv: cannot move 'LinuxData/Downloads/Downloads/Downloads/.' to 'LinuxData/Downloads/.': Device or resource busy
```

I am at a loss to figure out why this is happening and I need some guidance.

Comment: @sudodus I need the dot because I am trying to move the contents of the directory, not the directory itself. I do not understand why the depth of the source should be a factor. This command has been issued immediately following a system reboot.

Comment: Have a peek [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11241/135634). That may get you sorted. You can find and kill the process that's making the device report as busy.

Comment: `pathlld` may help you figure it out. https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld

Comment: You can also try to find the PID of the program that opens the file using `lsof`, with the PID, you can kill it with `kill -9 [PID]` (if you know killing it would not be harmful).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using `cp -R` rather than `mv`.